# PHP logout of 10 mins inactivity fails

Tags: php

**code part of Login.php**

```
            else if( ($row['Password'] == md5($pass)) ){
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['FName'];
                    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
                    header("Location: welcome.php");
            }
```

**Whole code of welcome.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ){ //session  verification
    header("Location: login.php");
}
else{
    echo "Welcome, ". $_SESSION['user']. "<br>";
    echo "<a href='logout.php'> Logout </a>";
}

if( $_SESSION['last_activity'] < (time() - 600) ){ //time in seconds, 10 minutes
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
else{
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
}
```

?>

Question: Even I refresh the page after 10 minutes, welcome.php page kept logged in. What is wrong? Thanks

Comment: I think you might need a client side code to trigger that server side event. Try using javascript to run that block of code (ajax)

Comment: Do you call session_start in your login.php?
Further you should also destroy the session when the first condition fails (session verification). You should also call die(); after you set the header (If exit does the same I do not know. And most important: DO NOT USE MD5. This is a highly insecure hashfunctions and does not provide enough security

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi, I have no javascript knowledge. :(

Comment: Javascript is quite easy to learn, but I recommend learing pure/vanilla javascript first before you delve into libraries like jquery so you get a firm grip of the language. W3schools.com has step by step tutorials. Check it out

Comment: @JRsz. Yes. I have session_start in login.php. If md5 is insecure, what else to be used? thaks

Comment: you could use sha 256 or even better sha 512 ( http://php.net/manual/de/function.hash.php ) You should also salt your pass that means append or prepend a random fixed string of a rather long length (64-128 chars for example) I looked it up, exit and die do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
$last_activity = time() - $_SESSION['last_activity'];

if( $last_activity >= 600 ){ //time in seconds, 10 minutes
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
```